# Automatic Webuzo third party packages updates increasing my disk use

Tags: centos, centos7, centos6

I'm running a self managed CentOS and I've noticed that in 2 weeks my disk space increased like 3Gb out of nowhere, and I believe it was already increasing before. I spent months working on localhost and around 3 months ago decided to republish my website, so basically it's a website without traffic and it's almost stopped, so I don't believe that's the site increasing in file size, neither mysql size. What I realized was that every week I get at least one automatic update of webuzo third parties apps, apps like Joomla, Magento, and other other CMS, and here's the catch: They're just packages, I'm not using any of them and I'm not willing to use any of them. I have reasons to believe that they are the ones causing this mess. Here's the mail that I receive weekly:

```
Software Updates ( site address goes here )
Inbox

Server Webuzo via  *site address goes here* 
8:52 AM (10 hours ago)
to me

The following software were updated during Automatic Cron Updates:
Backdrop CMS 1.17.4 - Successful

The logs of the Updates are as follows:
WordPress
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Joomla 2.5
Current package version is latest......Continuing

PrestaShop 1.6
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Joomla
Current package version is latest......Continuing

OpenCart 1.5
Current package version is latest......Continuing

AbanteCart
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Drupal 7
Current package version is latest......Continuing

phpBB
Current package version is latest......Continuing

SMF
Current package version is latest......Continuing

WHMCS
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Open Real Estate
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Magento 1.9
Current package version is latest......Continuing

MyBB
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Dolphin
Current package version is latest......Continuing

pH7CMS
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Moodle 3.5
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Laravel
Current package version is latest......Continuing

OpenCart
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Concrete5
Current package version is latest......Continuing

ClipBucket
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Oxwall
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Gallery
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Pubvana
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Piwigo
Current package version is latest......Continuing

ownCloud
Current package version is latest......Continuing

MODX
Current package version is latest......Continuing

OSClass
Current package version is latest......Continuing

CodeIgniter
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Roundcube
Current package version is latest......Continuing

CE Phoenix
Current package version is latest......Continuing

MediaWiki 1.27
Current package version is latest......Continuing

e107
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Xoops
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Jcow
Current package version is latest......Continuing

osCommerce
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Vtiger
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Elgg
Current package version is latest......Continuing

CMS Made Simple
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Dolibarr
Current package version is latest......Continuing

AEF
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Chamilo
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Moodle
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Seo Panel
Current package version is latest......Continuing

yii
Current package version is latest......Continuing

osTicket
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Open Source Social Network
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Drupal
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Zen Cart
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Coppermine
Current package version is latest......Continuing

PHP-Fusion
Current package version is latest......Continuing

phpMyAdmin
Current package version is latest......Continuing

phpList
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Geeklog
Current package version is latest......Continuing

WebMail Lite
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Composr
Current package version is latest......Continuing

LimeSurvey
Current package version is latest......Continuing

HESK
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Bootstrap
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Feng Office
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Vanilla
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Zikula
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Akaunting
Current package version is latest......Continuing

YetiForce
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Magento
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Revive Adserver
Current package version is latest......Continuing

jQuery
Current package version is latest......Continuing

WebsiteBaker
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Serendipity
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Dotclear
Current package version is latest......Continuing

BoxBilling
Current package version is latest......Continuing

DokuWiki
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Loaded Commerce
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Mibew Messenger
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Zenphoto
Current package version is latest......Continuing

b2evolution
Current package version is latest......Continuing

ProjectSend
Current package version is latest......Continuing

PHP-Nuke
Current package version is latest......Continuing

TomatoCart
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Drupal 6
Current package version is latest......Continuing

WebCalendar
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Matomo
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Podcast Generator
Current package version is latest......Continuing

SugarCRM
Current package version is latest......Continuing

eyeOS
Current package version is latest......Continuing

BlackNova Traders
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Textpattern
Current package version is latest......Continuing

SquirrelMail
Current package version is latest......Continuing

TheHostingTool
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Nextcloud
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Yclas
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Etano
Current package version is latest......Continuing

RainLoop Webmail
Current package version is latest......Continuing

StatusNet
Current package version is latest......Continuing

phpFreeChat
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Live helper chat
Current package version is latest......Continuing

LiteCart
Current package version is latest......Continuing

PunBB
Current package version is latest......Continuing

SLiMS
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Open Journal Systems
Current package version is latest......Continuing

CakePHP
Current package version is latest......Continuing

PyroCMS
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Mautic
Current package version is latest......Continuing

WeBid
Current package version is latest......Continuing

SilverStripe
Current package version is latest......Continuing

thirty bees
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Question2Answer
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Pydio
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Claroline
Current package version is latest......Continuing

TinyWebGallery
Current package version is latest......Continuing

YOURLS
Current package version is latest......Continuing

HumHub
Current package version is latest......Continuing

SuiteCRM
Current package version is latest......Continuing

FrontAccounting
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Collabtive
Current package version is latest......Continuing

ProcessWire
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Tiki Wiki CMS Groupware
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Symfony
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Subrion
Current package version is latest......Continuing

qdPM
Current package version is latest......Continuing

TYPO3 6
Current package version is latest......Continuing

CubeCart
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Nibbleblog
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Invoice Ninja
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Zend
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Form Tools
Current package version is latest......Continuing

TYPO3 45
Current package version is latest......Continuing

X-Cart
Current package version is latest......Continuing

dotProject
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Contao
Current package version is latest......Continuing

SPIP
Current package version is latest......Continuing

PeoplePods
Current package version is latest......Continuing

FluxBB
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Booked
Current package version is latest......Continuing

eFront
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Rukovoditel
Current package version is latest......Continuing

XMB
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Open Source Point of Sale
Current package version is latest......Continuing

bbPress
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Sitemagic CMS
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Quick.Cart
Current package version is latest......Continuing

EPESI
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Phorum
Current package version is latest......Continuing

ImpressPages
Current package version is latest......Continuing

OpenNewsletter
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Symfony2
Current package version is latest......Continuing

GRAV
Current package version is latest......Continuing

SimpleInvoices
Current package version is latest......Continuing

CumulusClips
Current package version is latest......Continuing

MyWebSQL
Current package version is latest......Continuing

MediaWiki
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Lazarus
Current package version is latest......Continuing

PASTE
Current package version is latest......Continuing

phpAlbum
Current package version is latest......Continuing

LifeType
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Quick.CMS
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Mantis Bug Tracker
Current package version is latest......Continuing

eXtplorer
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Redaxscript
Current package version is latest......Continuing

sNews
Current package version is latest......Continuing

OrangeHRM
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Soholaunch
Current package version is latest......Continuing

ProjectPier
Current package version is latest......Continuing

PopojiCMS
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Moodle 2.6
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Privacy Policy Generator
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Nucleus
Current package version is latest......Continuing

AngularJS
Current package version is latest......Continuing

HTMLy
Current package version is latest......Continuing

GLPI
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Moodle 2.0
Current package version is latest......Continuing

webtrees
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Chyrp
Current package version is latest......Continuing

PHP QR Code
Current package version is latest......Continuing

ImpressCMS
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Blesta
Current package version is latest......Continuing

LittlePoll
Current package version is latest......Continuing

SIDU
Current package version is latest......Continuing

OctoberCMS
Current package version is latest......Continuing

PmWiki
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Monstra
Current package version is latest......Continuing

phpwcms
Current package version is latest......Continuing

X2CRM
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Sales Syntax
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Dokeos
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Moodle 3.7
Current package version is latest......Continuing

AmpJuke
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Microweber
Current package version is latest......Continuing

EGroupware
Current package version is latest......Continuing

jobberBase
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Tiny Tiny RSS
Current package version is latest......Continuing

ElkArte
Current package version is latest......Continuing

UNA
Current package version is latest......Continuing

4images
Current package version is latest......Continuing

InvoicePlane
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Open Business Card
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Adminer
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Faveo Helpdesk
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Chevereto Free
Current package version is latest......Continuing

The Bug Genie
Current package version is latest......Continuing

WonderCMS
Current package version is latest......Continuing

EspoCRM
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Vision Helpdesk
Current package version is latest......Continuing

TCExam
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Arfooo
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Lychee
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Impleo
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Zurmo
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Arastta
Current package version is latest......Continuing

wallabag
Current package version is latest......Continuing

SitePad
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Omeka
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Kohana
Current package version is latest......Continuing

webERP
Current package version is latest......Continuing

LetoDMS
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Family Connections
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Ampache
Current package version is latest......Continuing

PhpGedView
Current package version is latest......Continuing

PHProjekt
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Kanboard
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Simple PHP Poll
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Advanced Poll
Current package version is latest......Continuing

AlegroCart
Current package version is latest......Continuing

InfiniteWP
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Vue.js
Current package version is latest......Continuing

FUDforum
Current package version is latest......Continuing

liveSite
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Bludit
Current package version is latest......Continuing

SiteCake
Current package version is latest......Continuing

HelpDeskZ
Current package version is latest......Continuing

ATutor
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Storytlr
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Pimcore
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Firefly III
Current package version is latest......Continuing

UIkit
Current package version is latest......Continuing

WikkaWiki
Current package version is latest......Continuing

FileRun
Current package version is latest......Continuing

TaskFreak
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Monsta FTP
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Codiad
Current package version is latest......Continuing

ChurchCRM
Current package version is latest......Continuing

Group Office
Current package version is latest......Continuing
```

------ There's way more, but I can't place more text here --------------

```
osTicket 1.12
Current package version is latest......Continuing

From Webuzo Cron Jobs ( IP address goes here )
```

I need to know how to address and solve the issue, since my server won't do a thing about it, which means  I want to remove all packages, because I don't use any of them. I still want to keep whatever system app is installed though. They gave me a tutorial teaching how to do that, but their tutorial only talks about system apps. Which SSH commands should I use here? Can this be solves with some kind of control panel?

If I keep those third parties packages there, they'll keep automatically updating until they flood my entire disk space.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is in the Webuzzo Admin interface (the serverip:port that it gave you after you installed Webuzzo). Is to *disable and remove* these unwanted applications.

It should then be unlisted *and* cease to receive further updates as it will be removed. So it should give you most if not all of your disk space back as well.

Comment: What's with these down votes, what did we do wrong?

Comment: I know right? You were asking WHY your disk was being eaten which IS a infrastructure concern AND you asked about the application in question. There is a zillion questions about Windows' applications yet they aren't down voted. REALLY WERID!

Comment: lol, oh the smell of linux user sarcasm in the morning. xD